# In an ASP.NET Core web application how can I execute an async task return a message to the user then execute another task if the task ran as expected?

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await

In an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor pages application, I want to execute a lengthy task, then immediately return a message to the client, *then* execute another task *IF* the long running tasks completes as expected.

- Task A is the long running script that creates a database
- Task B inserts some data into the databases tables after the Task A is complete if the result is as expected.

I tried the code below but it appears to cause the application to hang the entire length of the long running task.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Task<int> TASK_A = sql_operationA();

        TASK_A.ContinueWith(async result => {
            if (await result > 0)
                sql_operationB());
                });

        RequestSuccess = true;
        StatusMessage = "TASK A WAS A SUCCESS PLEASE ALLOW 2-3 MINUTES TO SEE YOUR RESULTS.";
    }

    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`async-await` won't change how HTTP works: 1 request has 1 response.

If you need the server to send something to the client other than a response to a request, use something like SignalR.